# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly after starting mysql service in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Sorry for my English. I have some problem in starting mysql service on Xampp control panel. I follow the steps from this site https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece because I want use mysql as type server on phpmyadmin and not mariadb as a default.

I followed those steps once and it worked but because of some reasons I had to unistall Xampp and mysql server, and now I can't start it. I've already read some questions but none of them helped me at all.

The error that appear at console is:

> 20:12:28  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>  
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>  
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>  
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>  
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>  
>   20:12:28  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

The error log is:

> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
>   2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>   2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
>   2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
>
> 2018-06-10 18:38:54 30a8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   2018-06-10 18:38:54 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835037
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12624 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>   2018-06-10 18:38:56 12456 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '10.1.13-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
>   2018-06-10 18:41:15 12648 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2018-06-10 18:41:15 12648 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   2018-06-10 18:41:16 12632 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:16 12648 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   2018-06-10 18:41:17 12648 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1836500
>   2018-06-10 18:41:17 12648 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
>
> 2018-06-10 18:41:27 31fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   2018-06-10 18:41:27 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 12796 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 12796 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 12796 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1836500
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 14076 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 12796 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:28 12796 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:29 12796 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '10.1.13-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
>   2018-06-10 18:41:49 13408 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2018-06-10 18:41:49 13408 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   2018-06-10 18:41:49 13876 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>   2018-06-10 18:41:49 13408 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   2018-06-10 18:41:50 13408 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1836510
>   2018-06-10 18:41:50 13408 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution? I am stuck at the same problem.